# Using multipe HTML5 canvas's to layer images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I started a web based game engine a while back, but used primarily jQuery to handle the sprites and animation, now I am learning the power of HTML5, by moving the game canvas to HTML5. So here's issue I am having: I'm using multple canvas as suggested from http://html5.litten.com/layers/canvaslayers.html to layer images.

This is not working for me, even if I set z-index to 999999: Here's my code->

http://snipt.org/xoKn

The objects layer is not on top of the tiles, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is having a similar problem I managed to solve this by loading the first layer first then the lowest layer last. Apparently it seems that whatever is loaded first will be on top.

So my solution was to just move m objects loop above my tiles loop. Interesting to me, had no idea it mattered what loads first.

Answer (score 1):

The code should work (at least the canvas handling part). I looked at your script and there may be the problem with loading images. You have

```
var tile = new Image();
tile.src = tiles[i]['bg'];
tilesCtx.drawImage(tile, tiles[i]['col']*32, tiles[i]['row']*32);
```

but it won't work since image is not loaded yet. Instead you should use

```
tile.onload = function(){
  tilesCtx.drawImage(tile, tiles[i]['col']*32, tiles[i]['row']*32);
}
```

or something like that (i.e. you won't have a reference to the `i` variable so it needs to be modified).

Note that in the tutorial they use `setInterval(drawAll, 20);` which makes it work after a while (since after a time all images will be loaded).

Of course you may lose ordering of images (although this does not seem to be important), so [preloading](http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/12/28/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/) all images at the begining and then drawing them all at once is a good idea. Give it a try and let us now if it works!

Comment: If I used your suggestion then the image object would not exist for tile, thus loading nothing at all. Th i variable is to index my array in my for loop. setInterval only sets a 20 millisecond delay and repeats that function every 20 milliseconds. I'm not sure why the image is not loading on top of the tilesCanvas. For example, if I don't load the tilesCanvas the objects load fine by themselves. The thing is everything is being loaded, but the tiles are being loaded on top of the objects, making it to where I cannot see them. In this case it's only 1 object being loaded.

Comment: I do understand that `i` variable is an index. :) Still preloading is a good choice. Unfortunetly I do not know PHP and I don't know what this script of yours does. :) SetInterval may not work for (lets say) first 10 calls, but it will later. But now I understand your problem correctly. I do not understand why this code does not work for you (assuming that images are loaded). It should (it works for me). Perhaps some other script/stylesheet overrides your z-index? I'm out of ideas. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the time and effort, I think I will just play around and see what happens. Could be something minor that I'm just not catching. This is really day 3 of HTML5 for me, once again I appreciate the help.